# Are there any forms in California that brings two defendants to court?

Tags: court, civil

Or do I just file for a case regularly and name the case name "person vs defendant 1 vs defendant 2". Then I give a summons sheet to both defendants respectively.

Case type: Civil
State: California

Answer (score 3):

If you are directly suing two people regarding a shared set of circumstances (e.g. two co-signers on a promissory note to plaintiff, or two people who both contributed to causing an accident burting the plaintiff), the caption and name of the lawsuit is:

PERSON v. DEFENDANT1 and DEFENDANT2.

The entire complaint together with a summons directed at DEFENDANT1 goes to DEFENDANT1 and the entire complaint together with a summons directed at DEFENDANT2 goes to DEFENDANT2.

There are cases that do have captions like PERSON v. AWESOME PERSON v. SUPERAWESOME PERSON. But that means that PERSON sued AWESOME PERSON, and then AWESOME PERSON, after being sued by PERSON, then turned around and filed what is called a "third-party complaint" against SUPERAWESOME PERSON.

A typical fact pattern there would be LANDLORD v. TENANT for damage to property and TENANT v. SUBTENANT to indemnify TENANT for damage actually done by SUBTENANT for which TENANT is nonetheless responsible to LANDLORD.